# Which is the better way to call a method that is only available to one class that implements an interface but not the other one?

Tags: java, coding-style

Basically I need to execute different actions given a certain condition. The existing code is written this way

Base interface

```
// DoSomething.java
interface DoSomething {

   void letDoIt(String info);
}
```

Implementation of the first worker class

```
class DoItThisWay implements DoSomething {
  ...
}
```

Implementation of the second worker class

```
class DoItThatWay implements DoSomething {
   ...
}
```

The main class

```
   class Main {
     public doingIt(String info) {
        DoSomething worker;
        if (info == 'this') {
          worker = new DoItThisWay();
        } else {
          worker = new DoItThatWay();
        }
        worker.letDoIt(info)
     }
```

This code works ok and is easy to understand.

Now, due to a new requirement, I need to pass a new piece of information that is only make sense to `DoItThisWay`.

My question is: does the following coding style good to handle this requirement.

**Use new class variable and method**

```
// Use new class variable and method

class DoItThisWay implements DoSomething {
  private int quality;
  DoSomething() {
    quality = 0;
  }

  public void setQuality(int quality) {
    this.quality = quality;
  };

 public void letDoIt(String info) {
   if (quality > 50) { // make use of the new information
     ...
   } else {
     ...
   }
 } ;

}
```

If I do it this way, I need to make the corresponding change to the caller:

```
   class Main {
     public doingIt(String info) {
        DoSomething worker;
        if (info == 'this') {
          int quality = obtainQualityInfo();
          DoItThisWay tmp = new DoItThisWay();
          tmp.setQuality(quality)
          worker = tmp;

        } else {
          worker = new DoItThatWay();
        }
        worker.letDoIt(info)
     }
```

Is it a good coding style? Or can I just cast it

```
   class Main {
     public doingIt(String info) {
        DoSomething worker;
        if (info == 'this') {
          int quality = obtainQualityInfo();
          worker = new DoItThisWay();
          ((DoItThisWay) worker).setQuality(quality)
        } else {
          worker = new DoItThatWay();
        }
        worker.letDoIt(info)
     }
```

Comment: Why not just pass `quality` into the constructor for `DoItThisWay`?

Comment: I probably need to revise my question... because for performance reason the construction of `DoItThisWay` and `DoItThatWay` are done once in the constructor of `Main`. `Main` is a long living class and `doingIt` is called many times over and over.

Comment: Yes, updating your question would be a good idea in that case.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the `setQuality` method will be called multiple times during the lifetime of the `DoItThisWay` object?

Comment: Why not change the interface? `DoItThatWay` can simply ignore the `quality` parameter which could be null...

Comment: Long lived mutable `class`? Ouch. Use a flywight  pattern or something to avoid.

Comment: There is no relevant difference between the two versions you presented. From a logical standpoint, they do the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that `quality` needs to be set alongside each `letDoIt()` call on a `DoItThisWay()`.

The issue I see arising here is this: You are introducing [temporal coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) (i.e. what happends if you forget to call `setQuality()` before calling `letDoIt()` on a `DoItThisWay`?). And the implementations for `DoItThisWay` and `DoItThatWay` are diverging (one needs to have `setQuality()` called, the other not).

While this might not cause issues right now, it may come back to haunt you eventually. It might be worthwhile to take another look at `letDoIt()` and consider if the quality information might need to be part of the `info` you pass through it; but this depends of the details.

Answer (score 15):

> Is it a good coding style?

From my point of view neither of your versions is. First having to call `setQuality` before `letDoIt` can be called is a [temporal coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/). You're stuck viewing `DoItThisWay` as an derivative of `DoSomething`, but it isn't (at least not functionally), it's rather something like a

```
interface DoSomethingWithQuality {
   void letDoIt(String info, int quality);
}
```

This would make `Main` rather something like

```
class Main {
    // omitting the creation
    private DoSomething doSomething;
    private DoSomethingWithQuality doSomethingWithQuality;

    public doingIt(String info) {
        DoSomething worker;
        if (info == 'this') {
            int quality = obtainQualityInfo();
            doSomethingWithQuality.letDoIt(info, quality);
        } else {
            doSomething.letDoIt(info);
        }
    }
}
```

You could on the other hand pass the parameters to the classes directly (assuming this is possible) and delegate the decision which one to use to a factory (this would make the instances interchangeable again and both can be derived from `DoSomething`). This would make `Main` look like this

```
class Main {
    private DoSomethingFactory doSomethingFactory;

     public doingIt(String info) {
         int quality = obtainQualityInfo();
         DoSomething doSomethingWorker = doSomethingFactory.Create(info, quality);
         doSomethingWorker.letDoIt();
     }
}
```

I am aware that you wrote that

> because for performance reason the construction of DoItThisWay and DoItThatWay are done once in the constructor of Main

But you could cache the parts that are costly to create in the factory and pass them to the constructor, too.

Comment: Argh, are you spying on me while I type answers? We make such similar points (but yours is much more comprehensive and eloquent) ;)

Comment: @CharonX I've already noticed (we even linked the same article by Mark Seemann ;) ). Thanks for the compliment.

Comment: Just being honest here - my answer is rather meh compared to yours :) I actually considered mentioning LSP (linking the wikipedia article) in my answer, but decided against it in the end (couldn't find the words to explain it right) - good thing too, that would have been too spooky :)

Comment: I fail to see the  LSP violation (at least I don't think there is one in the non-cast version of the code).

Comment: @DocBrown Yeah, it's debatable, but since the `DoItThisWay` requires the quality to be set before calling `letDoIt` it behaves differently. I'd expect a `DoSomething` to work the same way (not setting the quality before) for all derivatives. Does this make sense? Of course this is kind of blurry, since if we called the `setQuality` from a factory method the client would be agnostic about whether the quality has to be set or not.

Comment: What you saying is essentially, the LSP is violated as soon as different derivations have different properties or behave differently - so the only way of not violating the LSP would be by not making different derivations. Since you asked: no, that does not make sense to me. The LSP is about using different derivations of one base class in respect to the *contract of their base class*. So what we have to know for evaluating an LSP violation is the contract for `letDoIt`.

Comment: @DocBrown thanks for your input. I will revise that part (later today).

Comment: @DocBrown I'd assume the contract for `letDoIt()` is (lacking any additional info) "I can correctly execute (do whatever I do) if you provide me with `String info`". Requiring that `setQuality()` is called beforehand strengthens the precondition of calling `letDoIt()`, and thus would be a violation of LSP.

Comment: @CharonX: if, for example, there would be a contract implying that "`letDoIt`" shall not throw any exceptions, and forgetting to call "setQuality" would make `letDoIt` then throw an exception, then I would agree, such an implementation would violate the LSP. But those look like very artificial assumptions to me.

Comment: @DocBrown Good point. We don't know enough about the real code to make a good decision if LSP would be violated (I kinda assumed the function would not be permitted to throw exceptions since I vaguely remembered that they are part of the signature in Java, but other mechanisms handling a things like e.g. quality not being set may be in place). That said, the temporal coupling, plus the issue that any potential user of `DoItThisWay` needing to be aware of the need to `setQuality()` is making me uneasy.

Comment: Can the retrieval of the quality information be handled by the constructor of the object itself? If there is only one instance, this seems like it falls under app configuration.

Comment: This is a good answer.  The only thing I would add is some commentary on how disastrously bad temporal coupling is for a code base.  It's a hidden contract between seemingly decoupled components.  With normal coupling, at least it's explicit and easily identifiable.  Doing this is essentially digging a pit and covering it with leaves.

Answer (score 10):

Let's assume `quality` cannot be passed into the constructor, and the call to `setQuality` is required.

Currently, a code snippet like

```
    int quality = obtainQualityInfo();
    worker = new DoItThisWay();
    ((DoItThisWay) worker).setQuality(quality);
```

is way too small to invest too much thoughts into it. IMHO it looks a little bit ugly, but not really hard to understand.

Problems arise when such a code snippet grows and due to refactoring you end up with something like

```
    int quality = obtainQualityInfo();
    worker = CreateAWorkerForThisInfo();
    ((DoItThisWay) worker).setQuality(quality);
```

Now, you don't see immediately if that code is still correct, and the compiler won't tell you. So introducing a temporary variable of the correct type, and avoiding the cast, is a little bit more type-safe, without any real extra effort.

However, I would actually give `tmp` a better name:

```
      int quality = obtainQualityInfo();
      DoItThisWay workerThisWay = new DoItThisWay();
      workerThisWay.setQuality(quality)
      worker = workerThisWay;
```

Such naming helps to make [wrong code look wrong.](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/)

Comment: tmp might be even better named something like "workerThatUsesQuality"

Comment: @user949300: IMHO that's not a good idea: assume `DoItThisWay` gets more specific parameters - by what you suggesting, the name needs to be changed every time. It is better to use names vor variables which make the object type clear, not which methods names are available.

Comment: To clarify, it would be the name of the variable, not the name of the class.  I agree that putting all the capabilities in the class name is a poor idea.  So I'm suggesting that `workerThisWay` become something like `usingQuality`.  In that small code snippet it is safer to be more specific.  (And, if there is a better phrase within their domain than "usingQuality" use it.

Answer (score 2):

A common interface where the initialization varies based on runtime data usually lends itself to the factory pattern.

```java
DoThingsFactory factory = new DoThingsFactory(thingThatProvidesQuality);
DoSomething doSomething = factory.getDoer(info);

doSomething.letDoIt();
```

Then DoThingsFactory can worry about getting and setting the quality information inside the `getDoer(info)` method prior to returning the concrete DoThingsWithQuality object cast to the DoSomething interface.